# php/mysql validation to avoid duplicate entries

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Table LIST has items (ITEM_NAME) a user (NUM_USER) has selected, each item has a category (CATEGORY) .
Table ITEM has all possible items (NAME), each has a category (CATEGORY)

To display all items from a particular category that are not already in the users list I first select all items from the users list, then all items from a category, finally I diff the arrays to display items the user has not already selected.

The code below displays the two arrays properly but for the third part it just displays

```
Array ( )
```

no matter which order I put the 2 arrays for the diff. After a couple of days I wonder if there's something wrong w/my db schema - I think this should be a simple request.

```
$sqlall="SELECT ITEM_NAME FROM LIST WHERE NUM_USER=23";
$resultall = $conn->query($sqlall);
if ($resultall->num_rows > 0) {


while($row = $resultall->fetch_assoc()) {

     $new_array[ $row['id']] = $row;

    echo "<br>      
    ".$row["ITEM_NAME"]."";
}
echo "";

} else {
  echo "0 results for category $CAT_NAME";
}


echo "<HR>";

$sql2="SELECT NAME FROM ITEM WHERE CATEGORY='2' ORDER BY `ITEM`.`QUANTITY` DESC ";
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
     $new_array2[ $row['id']] = $row;
    echo "<br>  

    ".$row["NAME"]."";
}
echo "";

} else {
  echo "0 results for category $CAT_NAME";

}

echo "<HR>"; 

$remaining = array_diff($new_array, $new_array2);

print_r($remaining);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should work out a proper database schema and build one query to ask your database for the final result. Use the query language to ask the database, instead of pulling the data to PHP to manually "diff" the results. That's just overhead.

I've modified your schema a bit to get a working schema for SQLfiddle and for demonstration purposes.

Demo first: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/749fc/1/0

Basically, i've renamed List to Cart. The more important change is, that the cart stores items for a user by `user_id` to `item_id` relations. I left `quantity` out, that's not the problem, you know how to sort.

```
CREATE TABLE Cart
    (`id` int, `user_id` int, `item_id` int)
;
CREATE Table Items
    (`id` int, `category` varchar(55), `name` varchar(20), `description` varchar(50))
;

INSERT INTO Items
    (`id`, `category`, `name`, `description`)
VALUES
    (1, 'cars', 'red car', 'a red car'),
    (2, 'cars', 'blue car', 'a blue car without radio'),
    (3, 'cars', 'blue truck', 'a blue truck with big wheels'),
    (4, 'cars', 'a car', 'a car'),
    (5, 'cars', 'b car', 'b radio'),
    (6, 'cars', 'c truck', 'c truck'),
    (7, 'balls', 'blue ball', 'big blue ball')
;

INSERT INTO Cart
    (`id`, `user_id`, `item_id`)
VALUES
    (1, '1', '1'),
    (2, '1', '2'),
    (3, '1', '3'),
    (4, '2', '4'),
    (5, '2', '4'),
    (6, '2', '5')
;
```

Now, your goal is to

- display all items
- from a particular category
- that are not already in the users cart

Let's try to translate that to "rough" SQL:

- `Select * FROM items`
- `WHERE item.category = X`
- `AND item.id NOT_IN other_table`

Note: the key here is the `NOT IN` on the `WHERE` clause.

Well, of course, `other_table` has now to be replaced by a query to the other table:

- `Select all item_id`
- `FROM Cart`
- `WHERE user_id = Y`

So, when you combine both you end up with the following query:

```
SELECT
  item.id, item.category, item.name, item.description   
FROM
  Items item
WHERE 
  item.category = 'cars'
AND
  item.id NOT IN 
  (SELECT item_id value FROM Cart WHERE user_id = 2)
;
```